# Short story about AI waking up

Tags: story-identification, artificial-intelligence

I'm looking for a short story that's a dialogue between a researcher and an AI. The AI is told it's a person waking up in a dark room, and slowly comes to realize it's actually just a machine with no physical body.

The setting would be the lab they're in. I vaguely remember some plot twist where the one you think is the researcher is actually the AI, but I really don't remember.

I read the story online ~2 years ago, but I don't know the publish date. I don't know the name of the AI. The researcher was male. I don't think it was a well-known author.

Comment: @Richard none of those tropes get at what I'm asking here.

I think the only two characters are a scientist and the AI, and the entire short story consists of a dialogue between the two. The setting would be the lab they're in. I vaguely remember some plot twist where the one you think is the researcher is actually the AI, but I really don't remember.

Comment: Valentina: Soul in Sapphire is similar in some ways, but its not a short story.

Comment: I remember reading something like this. The AI is told that it has pre-installed memory of the person walking in a dark room to participate in an experiment (Turing test). So, when AI is started it feels completely as human Turing test participant.

Comment: Managed to find it: ["A Senseless Conversation" by Zach Barnett](https://sites.google.com/site/asenselessconversation/). Here is an older question about this story: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40518/ai-story-recognition-protagonist-turns-out-to-be-computer-in-the-end

Comment: @defaultlocale you got it! Thanks so much.