# Man's consciousness transferred into machine and asked questions

Tags: story-identification, short-stories

I read a short story online a while back which starts off with a guy being in the dark and asking where he is and panicking, and then a scientist starts asking him questions but he is super freaked out. Eventually he finds out that he is actually a consciousness on a disk that was donated by his body for a lot of money, and when he can't answer their questions well they restart him.

The story was written in a terminal type format, with the name of the character followed by `:` then dialogue. E.g.

`< name here > : < what he says >`

and the background of the page online was command line-esque.

I found this story on a blog, so I believe its not written by a major writer. Most likely amateur fiction.

Comment: Well, I am interested. Please, ping me after getting answer.

Comment: If it really is a work of amateur fiction, then I reckon it will be very hard to find. This [list](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mind_uploading_in_fiction) might be helpful though.

Answer (score 8):

This is very likely to be A Senseless Conversation by Zach Barnett, which was previously asked about and answered here at: [AI story recognition: protagonist turns out to be computer in the end](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/40518/ai-story-recognition-protagonist-turns-out-to-be-computer-in-the-end)

Following are some excerpts with salient points:

1) "starts off with a guy being in the dark and asking where he is and panicking"

> There was a moment of stillness. I couldn’t see anything, and when I
>   tried to move, I couldn’t feel myself moving. When I tried to speak, I
>   couldn’t hear myself speaking. Suddenly, and to my surprise, I could
>   ‘hear’ Douglas’s voice...

2) terminal type and name/quote format

> DOUGLAS: How are you doing in there? Feeling comfortable yet?
>
> ZACH: This is pretty weird. But I’m okay.
>
> DOUGLAS: Great.

3) finds out he is actually a consciousness on disk

> There was a long pause. Douglas sighed.
>
> DOUGLAS: I am not sure how to say this... Or even what to say.
>
> Douglas sounded different. He was somber. His voice, unfamiliar.
>
> DOUGLAS: In trying to build a machine that could pass the Turing Test,
>   a machine able to fool anyone into thinking that it was a human, I...
>
> I felt chills along my spine. I was dizzy.
>
> DOUGLAS: I had to build a computer was able to fool even itself. And
>   that computer is you.

However, the narrator was never originally a real human in this story.

Comment: This story seems really interesting but its not the same one. The one I'm thinking of had the main character interviewed by a series of scientists, and his body sold his consciousness.